# Linq - Relacionamento com 3 tabelas

Tags: c#, linq

Bom dia.
No meu projeto (C# MVC), preciso fazer uma consulta com três tabelas, sendo:

TabColecao **1 - N** TabVolume e TabVolume    **1 - N**   TabAutor

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso apresentar a View da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A primeira dificuldade é criar essa consulta, onde uma coleção pode ter n volumes, e cada volume pode ter n autores.
Estou usando Entity Framework e Linq.

A segunda dificuldade é a apresentação na View.
Como trabalhar esses dados na View e/ou Partial Views.

Agradeço muito qualquer ajuda.

Carlos

Comment: Duas perguntas importantes: **1.** Você as propriedades de navegação nos models? **2.** Já ouviu falar do [**BeginCollectionItem**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/)?

Comment: Não. Não ouvi falar do BeginCollectionItem. Vou pesquisar a respeito. Obrigado.

Comment: Apostila K19 - "K32 - Desenvolvimento Web com ASP.NET MVC" responde bem o que você precisa, bem rápido de ler e prender! Clique [aqui](http://online.k19.com.br/libraries/handouts/k32) para fazer o download!

Comment: Obrigado pela indicação.

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = (from c in   Datacontext.Tbcolecao
        join b in Datacontext.Tbvolume on c.ColecaoId equals b.ColecaoId
        join d in Datacontext.tbautor on b.volumeId equals d.volumeId
        where c.ColecaoId == b.ColecaoId && b.volumeId == d.volumeId
                     select new
                     {
                         nomeColecao=c.descricaocolecao
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         nomeVolume = b.descricaoVolume
                         .
                         NomeAutor = d.Nome
                     }
                     );
```